Почему в Grafana не вижу мониторинг Flask?
Подключил мониторинг
В конфиге prometheus указал где слушать.
Подключил панель https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/16111-flask-monitoring/
В итое захожу по адреса /metrics - показывает метрику.
А захожу в панель grafana - там говорит нет информации.
Что упустил?
PS: Панель с Node и Mysql также подключал(ну там правда systemd настраивал) - все показывает, а Flask не хочет.

Во-первых, не надо обижать Grafana ошибочным написанием, но то ладно

Во-вторых, начинаем с логичного вопроса — а почему вы решили что информация должна быть? Вышеупомянутая панель опирается на переменную app_name, значения для которой берутся из метрики flask_info — у вас такая есть?

а где это посмотреть?)

Странно получать такой вопрос на фоне того, что вы прямо в тексте вопроса написали где это посмотреть

@andreyma, не судите строго - я с prometheus и grafana первый день работаю и могу тупить)

Ну, и в первый день надо понимать что откуда берётся — панель в графане просит определённые метрики у прометеуса, тот их периодически запрашивает у прописанных в конфиге таргетов, ну а таргеты генерируют какие-нибудь метрики в формате словаря. Чтобы графана показала инфу, прометеус должен выдать ей нужные метрики, а чтобы они появились в прометеусе, их должен выдать таргет. Выдаёт ли ваш таргет эти метрики — это уже к вам вопрос (и у меня сильные подозрения что нет, потому что вышеупомянутый make_wsgi_app не имеет ни намёка на то, что он умеет создавать flask_info и другие такие метрики)

И вот вам ещё очень намекающий намёк — в описаниях панелей обычно пишут, откуда брать метрики для панели

@andreymal Я изменил с graphana на grafana. :)
